# Django sqlite driver generated SQL

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Need your help,especially in sqlite3:
started django book and on the first step i'm stuck. 
I have noticed that when creating an argument

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

in models.py the output must be like this

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "polls_poll" (

  "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,     
  "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL,    
  "pub_date" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

instead i'm getting

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "polls_poll" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL
);
```

;

Don't understand what i'm doing wrong. Tried to recreate a db but result stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using a different version of django than the one used in the `polls` tutorial. Also, you might be using a different version of SQLite. What I can say however, is that the SQL that is generated will work for what you want, and you should have no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it may has to do something with sqlite datatypes

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

SQL output in django tutorial is for PostgreSQL db engine, which I guess is not mentioned very clearly.

In case of SQLite, django converts timezone aware datetime into UTC. For PostgreSQL, it uses built-in timezone field instead:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql